# using MongoDb aggregation how to get the output another modal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate-functions, aggregation

hello my question is I am  getting  last four months records from database.i got the output but not getting my expected output  so how to do this can any one help me to solve this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:
    {CREATE_DATE:{$lte:new Date(),
    $gte:new Date(new Date().setDate(new 
    Date().getDate()-120))}}},
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id:{month:{$month:"$CREATE_DATE"},
            year:{$year:"$CREATE_DATE"}
        },
        avgofozone:{$avg:"$OZONE"}
    }
},
{
    $sort:{"year":-1}
},
{
    $project:{
        year:'$_id.year',
        avgofozone:'$avgofozone',
        month:'$_id.month',_id:0
    }
}
output :
{ "avgofozone" : 21.07777777777778, "year" : 2018, "month" : 2 }
{ "avgofozone" : 17.8, "year" : 2018, "month" : 3 }
{ "avgofozone" : 17.8, "year" : 2018, "month" : 1 }
expected output:
zone_type       year        january   febravary           march
avgofozone     2018         17.8      21.07777           17.8
```

Comment: @Veeram  help me to solve this...